# Serve string containing HTML as webpage

Tags: python, webserver, micropython

This code serves a webpage (using micropython on a microcontroller). I don't think the use of [microdot.py](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microdot/blob/main/src/microdot.py) (a Flask-like library) is important for the question, but I apologize this it not reproducible without that and a microcontroller connected to a wi-fi network.

```
from microdot import Microdot

myhtml =    """
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <p>LED is {state}</p>
            </body>
            </html>
            """
    
app = Microdot()

@app.route('/')
def index(request):
    state = 'OFF'
    return str(  myhtml.format(state=state)  ) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The browser interprets what it gets as text rather than HTML so on the browser it looks like the below instead of displaying "LED is OFF" without the HTML tags.

> ```
>        <!DOCTYPE html>
>        <html>
>        <p>LED is OFF</p>
>        </body>
>        </html>
> ```

I imagine a simple adjustment to my string formatting commands should fix this? Omitting the `str` call doesn't help.

Comment: Where is imports? Where is tag flask? Where minimal implementation of Microbot (empty class just to run app)? you code is not runable to help.

Comment: remove unused `request` param from method's `index` signature and you will see what you wand

Comment: Apologies it is not fully reproducible; I've added some info related to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation [Responces](https://microdot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#responses)

example [A Simple Microdot Web Server](https://microdot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#a-simple-microdot-web-server)

method `index` must to return next format

```
return myhtml.format(state=state), {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
```

Comment: That's very very close. The only problem is that `state` was not evaluated, so the webpage shows "LED is {state}". How can I get the string with state evaluated? I tried `myhtml = myhtml.format(state=state)` but that creates an error.

Comment: I have updated my answer without cast to string